# Pytesseract TesseractNotFoundError [Python 3]

Tags: python, tesseract

I am getting an Error using pytesseract. I installed it via pip install.

Code:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('frame_0000.png')

x = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('frame_0000.png'))
```

The Error occurs in the last line. (x = ...)

Result:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py",
>   line 194, in run_and_get_output
>       run_tesseract(**kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py",
>   line 165, in run_tesseract
>       proc = subprocess.Popen(command, **subprocess_args())   File "C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 707, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 990, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\Pytesseract_test.py", line 6, in 
>       x = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('frame_0000.png'))   File
>   "C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py",
>   line 286, in image_to_string
>       return run_and_get_output(image, 'txt', lang, config, nice)   File "C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py",
>   line 201, in run_and_get_output
>       raise TesseractNotFoundError() pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not
>   installed or it's not in your path

I am trying to get a workaround running but my inexperience prevents me from implementing this correctly:

```
tessdata_dir_config = '--tessdata-dir "<replace_with_your_tessdata_dir_path>"'
# Example config: '--tessdata-dir "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata"'
# It's important to include double quotes around the dir path.

pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='chi_sim', config=tessdata_dir_config)
```

Can somebody please help me solve this? I don't get the solutions provided online to work.

Comment: I gues pytesseract isn't installed properly

Comment: How to install it "properly"? Uninstalling and installing doesn't help

Comment: can you run pip3 show pytesseract? and see if it is present. If it is present open a python shell and import pytesseract and see if you get error

Comment: Damn Buddy. You really helped me there. I tried to figure out why this shit didnt work for several hours. And the mistake was that I installed it with pip and not with pip3 using Python3. Now it works. Thank you very much Sir.

Comment: cool. Shall I add it as a solution?

Comment: Sure .,.,.,.,.,.

Comment: I have added the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurred because the code is compiled using python3 but the module was installed using **pip**.
So the pytesseract module was installed to Python2 instead of Python3.
Installing using pip3 would solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

## For anyone else with this problem

> I had to go into the pytesseract.py file and changed my:
> `tesseract_cmd = 'tesseract'`
> To:
> `tesseract_cmd = '/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.05.02/bin/tesseract'`

*Disclaimer*: doing
`pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.05.02/bin/tesseract'`
did not fix the problem

Comment: `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=path/to/tesseract`

Answer (score 3):

~ For anyone else who still comes across this and is a beginner programmer( as I consider myself one)

*For Mac OS*

Try finding where the tesseract.exe is- if you installed it using
    **brew**, on your the terminal use:

```
>brew list tesseract
```

This should list where your tesseract.exe is, somewhere more or less like

```
> /usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.05.02/bin/tesseract
```

[Then following their instructions](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/):

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'
```

> pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.05.02/bin/tesseract'

should do the trick!